# How to speed up a complex MYSQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion

I have the following MYSQL query in a Cold Fusion Component being called from a ColdFusion website.  I have a custom take that basically builds a boolean query for the following fields: "PlaceName,Country,Adm1,adm2,adm3,locality".

```
<!--- SEARCH PLACES 2--->
<cffunction name="searchPlaces_full" access="public" returntype="query">
    <cfargument name="q" type="string" required="yes">


    <CF_BOOLSEARCH searchterm="#arguments.q#" field="PlaceName,Country,Adm1,adm2,adm3,locality " booloperator="and">
    <cfquery name="GetPlaces" datasource="#application.settings.dsn#">
    SELECT 
        places.CatID,
        places.PlaceName,
        places.PlaceID,
        places.Address1,
        places.PostalCode,
        places.Locality,
        places.Address2,
        places.ImageThumb,
        places.Adm1,
        places.Country,
        places.Adm2,
        places.Adm3,
        places.contributorid,
        places.lng,
        places.lat,
        places.verified,
        places.verified_by,
        places.verified_date
    FROM places INNER JOIN places_cats ON places.PlaceID = places_cats.PlaceID
    WHERE  
    <cfif len(trim(arguments.q))>
    (#PreserveSingleQuotes(boolsearch)#)
    <cfelse>
    1=0
    </cfif>
    AND places_cats.CATID IN (#arguments.categories#)
    GROUP BY 
        places.CatID,
        places.PlaceName,
        places.PlaceID,
        places.Address1,
        places.PostalCode,
        places.Locality,
        places.Address2,
        places.ImageThumb,
        places.Adm1,
        places.Country,
        places.Adm2,
        places.Adm3,
        places.contributorid,
        places.lng,
        places.lat,
        places.verified,
        places.verified_by,
        places.verified_date
        ORDER BY PlaceName
        </cfquery>


    <cfreturn getPlaces>
</cffunction>
```

There are 624227 records in the database.  If I do a search for Chappaqua, the actually SQL that gets run is as follows:

```
       SELECT 
        places.CatID,
        places.PlaceName,
        places.PlaceID,
        places.Address1,
        places.PostalCode,
        places.Locality,
        places.Address2,
        places.ImageThumb,
        places.Adm1,
        places.Country,
        places.Adm2,
        places.Adm3,
        places.contributorid,
        places.lng,
        places.lat,
        places.verified,
        places.verified_by,
        places.verified_date
    FROM places INNER JOIN places_cats ON places.PlaceID = places_cats.PlaceID
    WHERE  

    (((PlaceName LIKE '%chappaqua%') OR (Country LIKE '%chappaqua%') OR (Adm1 LIKE '%chappaqua%') OR (adm2 LIKE '%chappaqua%') OR (adm3 LIKE '%chappaqua%') OR (locality  LIKE '%chappaqua%')))

    AND places_cats.CATID IN (1,21,15,32,16,26,29,27,28,25,75,89,38,5,36,88,87,31,33,24,35,37,90,39,40,34,30,9,8,7,11,20,19,96,97,95,13,17,14,12,3,2,4,84,85,86)
    GROUP BY 
        places.CatID,
        places.PlaceName,
        places.PlaceID,
        places.Address1,
        places.PostalCode,
        places.Locality,
        places.Address2,
        places.ImageThumb,
        places.Adm1,
        places.Country,
        places.Adm2,
        places.Adm3,
        places.contributorid,
        places.lng,
        places.lat,
        places.verified,
        places.verified_by,
        places.verified_date
        ORDER BY PlaceName
```

I know it is ugly and complex.  It takes about 1836ms to run.  Is there any better way to write the query or code so that it speeds up the returned data in under a second?

Here is the Explain on the SQL:
[image: SQL EXPLAIN]

Comment: Show us your indexes. Show us your `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: You appear to use no aggregating functions, so what's with the GROUP BY?

Comment: @Strawberry They are trying to get `DISTINCT` rows

Comment: Suggest they use that then!

Comment: @Strawberry That's why the `GROUP BY` is frustrating with MySQL

Comment: I think there are two choices.  One is to accept the slowness.  The other is to make the user choose what field he is looking for.  I suggest the latter.  Checkboxes perhaps, to let him decide which fields to search.

Comment: OK... Will try to 'DISTINCT".  We have two indexes built on the tables. One is a unique Btree on PlaceID.  The other is a "normal" Btree on the following fields: PlaceName, Locality, adm1, adm2, Country.

Comment: In addition to posting the `EXPLAIN`, it is possible you could use an EXISTS clause and eliminate the need for `DISTINCT/GROUP BY` which could contribute to the slowness.

Comment: Ok... Not really sure how to post the Explain output, so here we go: 
'1,SIMPLE,places,ALL,"PRIMARY,by_paceid",,,,640584,Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1,SIMPLE,places_cats,ref,by_PlaceIDandCatID,by_PlaceIDandCatID,4,mapthepast.places.PlaceID,1,Using where; Using index; Distinct'

Comment: [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14654112/edit) and either include it as text (code formatted for readability) .. or just post a screen shot of it :)

Comment: Here is a screen capture of the Explain.http://www.screencast.com/t/prD504Zh1g

Comment: Does the table type matter when it comes to speed?  I don't know why, by the Places table is an InnoDB.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the engine is doing a full table scan of the table, then sorting the results for the `group by`.

The full table scan almost seems necessary because of the `like`s:

```
(((PlaceName LIKE '%chappaqua%') OR (Country LIKE '%chappaqua%') OR (Adm1 LIKE '%chappaqua%') OR (adm2 LIKE '%chappaqua%') OR (adm3 LIKE '%chappaqua%') OR (locality  LIKE '%chappaqua%')))
```

The issue is that an index on PlaceName cannot be used, because the initial characters are not fixed.

So . . . Can you remove the `group by`?  You can at least replace it with `distinct`, although I don't think that would affect the query plan.  Do you have an index on `place_cats(placeId, catId)`?  That would at least prevent the query from reading the category table so it could just do index lookups.

Can you limit the search only to words at the beginning of the fields?

The only other alternative that I can think of is to switch to using a full text index in MySQL.

Comment: OK... Shaving the wildcard off the beginning of the word does save a half second, but I would hate to have to do that.

Comment: Yes, I do have an index on place_cats(placeId, catId).

Comment: Yeah, wouldn't it be worth looking at doing a full-text search in place of all that LIKE stuff?

Comment: @user1224994 . . . One option is full text search (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).  It is possible that if you had a table of just the names and then joining that back would work in your case.  The smaller table would scan faster and the overhead of the join would be small on a not-very-selective query.